# Can I use latex exterior paint over oil based primer?

Tags: painting, paint

I'm in a time crunch. I have to get this storm door painted before the installer comes. I primed it with oil based primer, but don't have time to get oil based paint. Can I use the water based exterior paint that was used on my house?

[This is the paint](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/catalog/emerald-exterior-acrylic-latex-paint/?referringCategory=exterior-paint-coatings/paint/) I have.

I don't understand the difference latex, acrylic etc. and I am at work now.

Comment: You might be able to.  But you'd need to do a test first, and that will take more time than running to the store and getting an oil paint.

Comment: What kind of test?

Comment: Your link is for the interior, I assume you meant the exterior version.  An enamel should be a better choice for the door (harder finish, more scrubbable).

Comment: You're not doing the installer any favors by painting just before installation, unless you have 3 days to dry.  You're asking for a smudged finish.

Comment: I updated the link. I hope to give it one coat tonight. It will be about 15 hours before he handles it -  best I can do. I can't deal with painting around the hinges and hardware. This is a new door, so it's my chance.

Comment: Once installed and all holes drilled, removing/reinstalling isn't so bad.

Comment: Unless it's hung.

Comment: Even if it's hung it is a piece of cake to knock out the hinge pins and lay the door down on some saw horses. That kind of thing is done all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primers (of either base) can be top coated with either latex or oil.  Double check your primer label.

What doesn't work is an oil based topcoat (brittle film) over a latex topcoat (softer, flexible film).

An oil based primer is a good undercoat for exterior (or baths), due to its greater degree of waterproofing.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will check the label when I get home.

Comment: Painted the door, all seems well.

Comment: Painted with what?  Tell us the gory details!